# linking android application with google app engine datastore

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, jsp, jpa

i am looking for a link through a web service between an android application and an application that is deployed on google app engine.the user inputs data in the android application which has to be passed to the jsp and jpa application deployed on the google app engine.Can anyone please help...

Answer (score 1):

See [this article](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app) for how to authenticate against App Engine from inside your Android app. From there, how you interface is up to you: You can write a RESTful API, or use any number of HTTP-based RPC protocols to communicate between the Android app and the site. Which you choose depends on your needs, which you haven't detailed.